# Create an updated count column using EXISTING count column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table called transactions that looks like this:

```
transactions:
| id | PartNumber | Quantity |
```

I know that I can use the COUNT property in MySQL, which would give me the the duplicate part numbers in a new column called total_quantity:

```
 SELECT COUNT(transactions.id) AS total_quantity
 FROM transactions
 GROUP BY transactions.PartNumber
```

However, now I already have an existing quantity column and want to compute a new count quantity taking into account the previous one as well and updating it in the existing quantity column

What's the most efficient way of doing this?

For example: I want to go from this:

```
transactions
| id | PartNumber | Quantity |
| 1  |    123     |    1     |
| 2  |    124     |    2     |
| 3  |    125     |    2     |
| 4  |    124     |    2     |
| 5  |    124     |    3     |
| 6  |    126     |    4     |
| 7  |    125     |    1     |
| 8  |    127     |    2     |
```

To this:

```
transactions
| id | PartNumber | Quantity |
| 1  |    123     |    1     |
| 2  |    124     |    7     |
| 3  |    125     |    3     |
| 4  |    126     |    4     |
| 5  |    127     |    2     |
```

Comment: Please give some illustration on how your expected output would look like. Include bit of example data as well. We wouldn't want to go through one suggestion only for you to say "that's not how I imagine it, I would expect it to be something like this", then after an updated (or another) suggestion you say "close but still not there yet, because I would like something like this"... so, yeah

Comment: ok, just posted an example, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this sql request :

```sql
SELECT PartNumber, sum(Quantity) as 'SumQuantity' FROM transactions GROUP BY PartNumber
```

It will gives you sometings like this :

```
transactions
| PartNumber | SumQuantity |
|    123     |      1      |
|    124     |      7      |
|    125     |      3      |
|    126     |      4      |
|    127     |      2      |
```

You can find a code sample on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c1dad/1)